# Edit order products after invoice, but before shipping. Code? or extension?

Tags: orders, extensions, management

we sell clothing in sizes. Very often a customer emails 1 minute after placing the order "can i change the size". We ar enot looking for a full re-do of order management, grid etc. Just a way to quickly change the size of an order item. Or change the product from e.g. grey -> white shirt. Price is almost always the same.

can this be done easily through code? Or a simple extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, this is not possible for a reason. You need to credit the order to add quantity back to your stock again, multiple functions and methods are connected to the actions you need to take.

There will definitely be some kind of extension that hacks this functionality but this will cost you problems in the near future. I would rather look for a extension that makes the process quicker but not change it.

Its not really a answer but i hope you appreciate my look on the subject.

Cheers

Comment: Answered yes. Maybe we are/were looking for an extension. Or some method - other then complex programming to accomplish some form of exchange .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Kay Int Veen pointed out, this is not possible within the native Magento framework, which does not allow modifying submitted order items. I know of no extensions that does this, but you could implement one yourself. Conceptually, it's not that difficult, but you'll have to make sure your order item line amounts and totals do not change for historical reasons.

I suppose it depends how you're looking at the orders and fulfilling them, but could you simply use the order comment and have that printed to your picklist?

If you ***really*** need to do this, you will have to modify records in `sales_flat_order_item` (using Magento methods, of course). Some of the fields that must be modified are: `product_id`, `name`, `sku`, possible `product_options`, etc.. As you can imagine, this will be a hack no matter how you implement it, but it will serve your purpose with an admin interface and everything.

**Warning:** This is under the assumes absolutely no amount changes and that all amounts stay the same. If you have different prices for different options, then I don't recommend doing anything like this.

Comment: which file or method used by magento to load all details for edit order, So I can use the same after generate invoice I want to edit order.